# Rails method that accepts XML data from OAuth client application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, api, oauth

I have a method that creates a new item in my Rails app. This method is used together with the web form. User fills the form and then this method is called.

I'm turning now my application into an Oauth enabled one. How to implement this method so that an OAuth client could call it and provide all the data via XML?

Here is the method:

```
 def create
        @item = current_user.items.build(params[:item])
        @item.custom_id = current_user.items.count + 1
        if @item.save
          flash[:success]="Item is successfully created. Wanna add more?"
        else
           flash[:error]="Something went wrong. Have you added a title?"
        end
        redirect_to pages_home_path
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use respond_to and respond_with to return XML based data. [Here](http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2009/08/06/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-cleaner-restful-controllers-w-respond_with/index.html) you can find more information.

Comment: Thanks, pretty good link! I still wonder how the client application should form and call the create method?

Comment: Create and send POST request to /items url. Working with web application is just sending http requests to it, nothing more.